What causes the Ansible "The module ansible.legacy.setup was redirected to ansible.windows.setup, which could not be loaded" error?
I have a simple Ansible playbook executing against a Windows server and I get this error:
The module ansible.legacy.setup was redirected to ansible.windows.setup, which could not be loaded

This is the playbook:
---
- name: Test get values
  hosts: dc
  gather_facts: true
  become: true
  tasks:
  - name: Value of inventory_hostname
    debug: var={{ inventory_hostname }}

  - name: Value of ansible_hostname
    debug: var={{ ansible_hostname }}

  - name: Value of ansible_user
    debug: var={{ ansible_user }}

This is the hosts file:
[dc]
spwawsinfdc01

[dc:vars]
ansible_host=10.11.12.13
ansible_user=username
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_scheme=https
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation=true

I run the playbook with this command:
ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yaml --ask-pass

What is causing this module redirect error?

This module (ansible.windows.setup) is part of the ansible.windows collection (version 2.4.0). It seems that you don't have it installed. To install it, use:
ansible-galaxy collection install ansible.windows

